# Read Email in VB.NET / ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, outlook

**UPDATE**

Now, after trying to use EWS as an alternative I've been getting this new error message that I can't seem to fix :

**DTD is prohibited in this XML document.**

And yes I've given these code a try :

1. Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
2. settings.XmlResolver = Nothing
3. settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
4. settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD
5. Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(".xml", settings)

But it made no difference. Please Help!!

For your information : I'm trying to make this to **run in a web based version**

---

My code works perfectly during execution to read email using VB.NET.

Unfortunately this happen :

**"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"**

Additional Info:

1. I'm a company worker = email I want to retrieve is using company
   domain (eg: ...@company.com)
2. Windows 10
3. Microsoft Outlook 2016
4. Visual Studio 2012
5. .NET framework 4.5.1 & 4.5.2
6. I code it using Microsoft.Office.Interop

I've searched google for solution on how to handle the problem and so far no luck.

1. I've tried modifying DCOM
2. I want to download new security update from support.microsoft, but no luck with the company internet restriction

Please help. I've been stuck for almost a month on this problem

Comment: You're probably trying to Interop over the network. Not supported.

Comment: Use EWS instead

Comment: @sasfrog does this EWS use a thrid party app? If that so then I think my hands are tied, especially if I have to pay for it, since I am a company worker

Comment: @Jimi but the funny thing is, I've tried the same code but convert it into C# and it works

Comment: EWS is an interface for Exchange: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange client libraries/SDK freely available. Although if you’re using office 365 I’d suggest first looking at the Microsoft Graph API and see if it suits your purposes

Comment: @sasfrog do you have any website which use EWS with VB.NET as code reference? Thank you

Comment: I’ll leave that googling to you Lydia

Comment: @sasfrog it says this now "DTD is prohibited in this XML document" am I doomed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this happens if Outlook and your app are running in different security contexts (e.g. one app is running as an admin). Try to close Outlook before starting your app - if that works, you have mismatched security context.

Also keep in mind that Office apps (including Outlook) cannot run in a service (such as IIS).

Comment: after much digging I found out that it is impossible for me to read through Outlook app to a web based. So this answer is actually valid. And fyi I solved this problem by reading through the email server using EWS. Thanks for your answer.